# How to set up vuexfireMutations in Vuex store.js file

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuefire

I am attempting to build a Vue.js application that utilizes Vuexfire in the store.js file. My store.js file looks something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { vuexfireMutations, firestoreAction } from 'vuexfire'
import { db } from '@/main'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    items: []
  },
  mutations: vuexfireMutations,

  actions: {
    setEvents: firestoreAction(context => {
      return context.bindFirestoreRef('items', db.collection('dbItems'))
    }),
  },
})
```

I understand from the documentation that the `.bindFirestoreRef()` method is what binds Firestore to the Vuex store, while `firestoreAction` is a wrapper that injects `.bindFirestoreRef()` into the context object, so that it can be used as a method of the store (along the same lines as the commit method). The payload is then committed to mutations, while `vuexfireMutations` apparently handles the mutation of the state behind the scenes. Does this mean that `vuexfireMutations` is a method? What is the right term to describe `vuexfireMutations`? I really don't feel like the documentation explains very well what this imported item is. I'm just kind of having to guess that it is something that handles mutations, but what is the right term for it?

Comment: From the [doc](https://github.com/posva/vuexfire): this object "contains VuexFire internal mutations. They are all prefixed by vuexfire/. This object must be added in the root Store mutations object." This other [doc](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuexfire/getting-started.html#installation) explains that "In order to use Vuexfire, you must add the mutations exported by the package at the root of your store and only there.... This will add some mutations needed to keep your store state in sync with the remote database."

Comment: I see. Thank you!